# Two humans from another planet, lovers from a long time ago

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I read this book from the mid to late 90s.

There were humans on Earth but these two specific humans were from another planet. They were lovers from a long time ago, possibly thousands of years ago. They would lose each other periodically and then find each other again.

I think the time was set in current times but they were together in Egyptian times (they may have ruled together?) as well.

He dies then and he dies in the current time *as well* (I think) I'm not sure if they are reborn or what. These creatures are human but they somehow live a very long time and have seen a lot. It might be a love story.

Comment: Sounds vaguely like *the Eternal Champion* but I don't recall any Egyptian stuff from it.

Comment: It actually reminds me a lot of Hawkman and Hawkwoman from the DC universe, but you'd probably have recognized them or at least mentioned wings.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151926/finding-a-book-with-a-man-from-the-future-being-reincarnated-on-earth-in-past-ti (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 5):

Sounds a lot like the **Orion** series by **Ben Bova**
Orion is basically a troubleshooter for a race from far in the future who time travels to different periods and basically gets killed each time and travels on to another time, in each case he has a lover who follows him to each time and tries to teach him to take control of his own destiny from the "creators" who use him. The second book has some scenes during acient Egypt, but the first book is set during the near future, the mongols, and the far past with neandethals.

1. Orion (1984)
2. Vengeance of Orion (1988)
3. Orion in the Dying Time (1990)
4. Orion and the Conqueror (1994)
5. Orion Among the Stars (1995)
6. Orion and King Arthur (2012)

Answer (score 1):

The more I look for it, the more I think it might be the Christopher Pike *The Last Vampire* stories, "Red Dice" to be exact. Sorry for the vague information. Vampires may have been in it. Read this book around 20 years ago so the memory is bad. I'll let you know when I find out for sure. Have to order it or it very well may be in my garage.

An excerpt from Wikipedia entry for book 5:

> The story opens as Sita and the newly revived Seymour attend a seminar of an ancient Egyptian Seer named Suzama. Sita knew her personally and is interested to know that, in her Seer's eye, Suzama predicted the birth of God in three mortal forms at exact times. Krishna and Jesus Christ were two of these incarnations. Sita learns from Dr. Donald Seter, the man who discovered Suzama's Scripture and the founder of the Suzama Society, that Christ has been born again as her friend Paula's new born son (and Paula herself is actually Suzama reincarnated).

Book 5 also introduces the theme of aliens being involved, as well as vampires.

Comment: There are summaries of the books at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Vampire if you want to browse the details, assuming you haven't located the book in your garage. I have my doubts as the match seems superficial at best, but you'd know best, being the querent.

Answer (score 1):

This seems more like the plot from the recent film [Cloud Atlas](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1371111/?ref_=nm_knf_t2) and the novel of the same name by David Mitchell. [Cloud Atlas Novel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_Atlas_%28novel%29).  Both are about two characters who seem to gain knowledge from each previous incarnation.  The characters die but are brought forth again in a tale being read or watched by someone in the future.  This book is broken into several sections building to a final age in a distant future then brought back to the original timeline at the end.